# UIView Retina 4 doesn't work

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, interface-builder, iphone-5

I'm trying to update my application to catter for iPhone 5 4 inch retina screen.

I'm using custom nibs for different screen size versions as I want to show something different and make use of bigger screen.

I've created another nib and I'm properly calling it from initWithNib method.

This is what I'm getting:

[image]

It's only a start, I've setted background color of the View to black, but as you can see simiulator isn't scalling the view up. I don't know why. In IB there is 4 Retina View type selected. The dimensions are ok. I've checked everything I though of and still the same result.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

Here are my settings:

[image]

Comment: Have you given a lunch image and set it in the info section. If not then it will not pick the iPhone 5 stuff up. (Default-568h@2x.png)

Comment: I did. I've created previous screen (different controller with different nib) and there it is working just fine... I'm confused.

Comment: I am unsure then. For me i forgot to set the launch image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In IB do you have anything set in the Simulated Metrics panel for top bar or bottom bar as these will cause the view to shrink accordingly?

Comment: I've updated the first question with settings. Status bar, top bar, bottom bar are all setted as None

Comment: I'm accepting your answer as it would be probably the case for others that didn't setted their frame manualy :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok... I was just setting the frame in my app delegate and it was causing this issue. 
I need to look at my code more :)